# OpenACC nested loop dependency error

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, openacc, pgi

Please, I need some help with using OpenACC parallel computing model(C++). The problem is as following:

There is a dependency among vairables W, hbias, vbias (it should get updating of each iteration) and calculating means inside propup and propdown functions , but by using OpenACC on the code that is not avaliable . So each iteration functions would get the inital vlue of W, and biases. Note that, if the parallelization happend on the lower level it won't get a benefit. This is the code:

```
    void RBM::contrastive_divergence(int ** train_X, double learning_rate, int k) {


    int * input = new int[n_visible];

    double *ph_mean = new double[n_hidden];
    int *ph_sample = new int[n_hidden]; // CALUCLATED WITHIN COMPLETE CODE
    double *nv_means = new double[n_visible];
    int *nv_samples = new int[n_visible]; //CALUCLATED WITHIN COMPLETE CODE
    double *nh_means = new double[n_hidden];
    int *nh_samples = new int[n_hidden]; //CALUCLATED WITHIN COMPLETE CODE


    #pragma acc parallel 
    {

    #pragma acc loop gang private(input[0:n_visible],ph_mean[0:n_hidden],ph_sample[0:n_hidden], \
    nv_means[0:n_visible], nv_samples[0:n_visible], nh_means[0:n_hidden], \
    nh_samples[0:n_hidden])

    for (int ii = 0; ii<train_N; ii++) {

    #pragma acc loop vector
    for (int j = 0; j< n_visible; j++)
    input[j] = train_X[ii][j];


    sample_h_given_v(input, ph_mean);

    sample_v_given_h(h0_sample, nv_means);
    sample_h_given_v(nv_samples, nh_means);

        #pragma acc loop vector
        for (int i = 0; i<n_hidden; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<n_visible; j++) {
            #pragma acc atomic update
            W[i][j] += learning_rate * (ph_mean[i] * input[j] - nh_means[i] * nv_samples[j]) / N;
            }
        #pragma acc atomic update
        hbias[i] += learning_rate * (ph_sample[i] - nh_means[i]) / N;
        }

        #pragma acc loop vector
        for (int i = 0; i<n_visible; i++) {
        #pragma acc atomic update
        vbias[i] += learning_rate * (input[i] - nv_samples[i]) / N;
        }

    }

    }

    delete[] input;
    delete[] ph_mean;
    delete[] ph_sample;
    delete[] nv_means;
    delete[] nv_samples;
    delete[] nh_means;
    delete[] nh_samples;

    }

    #pragma acc routine vector
    void RBM::sample_h_given_v(int *v0_sample, double *mean){

        #pragma acc loop vector
        for (int i = 0; i<n_hidden; i++) {
            mean[i] = propup(v0_sample, W[i], hbias[i]);
        }
    }




    #pragma acc routine vector
    void RBM::sample_v_given_h(int *h0_sample, double *mean){

            #pragma acc loop vector
            for (int i = 0; i < n_visible; i++) {
                mean[i] = propdown(h0_sample, i, vbias[i]);
            }
    }


    #pragma acc routine seq
    double RBM::propup(int *v, double *w, double b) {
    double pre_sigmoid_activation = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j<n_visible; j++) {
    pre_sigmoid_activation += w[j] * v[j];
    }
    pre_sigmoid_activation += b;

    double x;
    x = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-pre_sigmoid_activation));

    return x;
    }

    #pragma acc routine seq
    double RBM::propdown(int *h, int i, double b) {
    double pre_sigmoid_activation = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j<n_hidden; j++) {
    pre_sigmoid_activation += W[j][i] * h[j];
    }
    pre_sigmoid_activation += b;

    double x;
    x = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-pre_sigmoid_activation));
    return x;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to increase your chances that somebody will help you it's probably good idea to format your code and make it readable. Put some minimum effort if you want something back.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding "independent" clause to "#pragma acc loop vector"?
You use "#pragma acc parallel" at the top.
So you have a responsibility to express dependencies or ensure the correctness of the result.